# How do I push a crease in to make this mesh more "smooth?"

Tags: mesh

It's simple really but I cannot figure out how to do this. It's a glass ceiling for a mall and I would like for the creases on both sides to be pushed outwards to make this mesh smoother.

I've tried using sculpting mode but that doesn't give me the results I want. I know what to do but not how to do it. Basically, I need a way to somehow pull the vertices along the curve outwards, that will pull the surrounding faces with it while the ends of the mesh stay in place.

Anyone have a clue on how to do this? Thanks.

[image: Top View]
[image: Bottom View]

Comment: It looks your mesh is made of triangles. Could you screenshot the wireframe?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect your topology might not be the best for this kind of object. Without suggesting mine *is* the best, or perfectly suits your purposes, here's a way of modelling it.

1. Starting with a half-cylinder, with loop-cuts as shown
2. Use the knife tool (<kbd>K</kbd>), cut a diagonal from the 2nd-bottom longitude to the 2nd-top longitude just inside the existing loops, and then extend the diagonal to the boundaries,  using the knife tool again, this time constraining it. (<kbd>K</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>)
3. <kbd>X</kbd> Delete the inside faces, and ensuring the pivot is set on the center-line (see the last item) <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd>, scale the center section out appropriately
4. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>, from the Edge Menu, 'Bridge Edge loops' having selected the loops on the sides of the gap.
5. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> cut in some more holding loops .. (pressing <kbd>E</kbd> makes the new loop parallel to one side or the other, and pressing <kbd>F</kbd> flips which side)
6. Assign a Mirror modifier, and maybe a Subdivision modifier..

By using <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> to slide edge-loops (with <kbd>E</kbd> and <kbd>F</kbd>in the same way as when you made them,) you can tighten or loosen the creases between the sections by moving the holding loops in or out, or you can even get rid of the central loops. If you want to completely soften the creases, careful use of <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> to scale vertices out along their own normals, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> Vertex Menu > 'Smooth Vertex' will get you there, but that's destructive, so save snapshots.

[image]

This result may not be precisely what you want, but variations on this sort of approach may work for you

[image]

Here's a contrasting example, where the central loop in the crease has been removed, and its outside loops slid outwards, to soften the transition:

[image]